# Grub rescue after removing Ubuntu partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, grubrescue

I removed the Ubuntu partition (Windows 10 dual-booting) and after restarting my computer, I have been stucked in grub rescue. I understood that my grub is installed in MBR and I should to recover the MBR with bootable Windows 10 media because the bootloader was removed but after I create the USB media, my laptop ports don't connect the USB (that happend 2-3 months ago). Soo what I should to do?
*I haven't installed any updates for 2-3 months ago, as implied. 
*Laptop Lenovo

Comment: As you already said you should install the Windows bootloader. However you may want to boot into windows directly from grub. Follow the steps on these answers: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148041/recovering-from-grub-rescue-crash

Comment: Tried and still not working. Every partition is "unknown filesystem".

Comment: have you tried to enter BOOT Menu and Choose Windows10 from there?

Comment: There is no Window 10 from the BOOT Menu. I'm trying with DVD but what tool should I use to make it Windows 10 bootable? MediaCreation tool takes me to an error.

Comment: @Imfao3zWin you removed the Ubuntu Partition when it is dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu rite. So you did not disturb your Windows OS. you need to remove the Grub now. If you are not able to boot to windows at this stage.. go with Live Session of Ubuntu and then access the /boot folder and remove the grub folder from there. Can you attach the pic when you open GParted from Live Session of Ubuntu?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jzlrpi What should I do to make the DVD bootable or why I can't make it?

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-windows#1

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jzm86m

Comment: So know what to do ?